# OSMDroid Overlays Multiple Static and one Dynamic

Tags: android, osmdroid

In my application, I already have some static overlays on the map, and one dynamic which changes it's place when GPS coords change.

My problem is that, when the GPS coords change, I have to clear the dynamic overlay and create a new one, but when I do that, it clears all the overlays, using:

```
mapView.getOverlays().clear();
```

So, I'm trying to find the better way to do it.

Clear all the overlays and then place them again on the map (memory consuming) or can I clear a specific overlay?

Thanks

**Edit:**

*This is the dynamic marker:*

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d("Location", "onLocationChanged with location " + location.toString());

    mLatitude = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
    mLongitude = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);

    GeoPoint gpt = new GeoPoint(mLatitude,mLongitude);

    markerYou.clear();
    markerYou.add(new OverlayItem(getString(R.string.markerYou), getString(R.string.markerYouDescription), gpt));

    mMyLocationOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(markerYou, new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(ShowMap.this, getString(R.string.markerYouDescription), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(ShowMap.this, getString(R.string.markerYouDescription),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    }, mResourceProxy);

    mapView.getOverlays().clear();
    mapView.getOverlays().add(mMyLocationOverlay);
    mapView.invalidate();

    mapController.setCenter(gpt);
}
```

*This is the function that places the static markers:*

```
public void putPlacesOfInterest(){
    this.dh = new DataHelper(ShowMap.this);
    List<Pontos> list = this.dh.selectAll();
    for(Pontos p : list){
        markerPlaces.add(new OverlayItem(p.getName().toString(), p.getName().toString(), new GeoPoint(p.getLat(), p.getLng())));
    }
    mMyLocationOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(markerPlaces, new OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongPress(int index, OverlayItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(ShowMap.this, "Item " + item.mTitle, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(int index, OverlayItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(ShowMap.this, "Item " + item.mTitle, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }

    }, mResourceProxy);

    mapView.getOverlays().add(mMyLocationOverlay);
    mapView.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: What does the declaration of markerYou look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved using this solution:

[Android MapView Can't Remove Marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633841/android-mapview-cant-remove-marker)

Thanks for the help NickT!

Answer (score 3):

The real problem is that you are adding mMyLocationOverlay has many time has you call mapView.getOverlays().add(mMyLocationOverlay);
So in fact when you try to clear mMyLocationOverlay you are only clearing 1 instance. Meaning you may have 20 instances to mMyLocationOverlay.

Just wanted to point out the real cause of the problem, if someone needs it for the future.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I haven't worked on this ever since, but it's nice to update the question with good information for others. Thanks again! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the .size()  method of the list of overlays just before you add the dynamic one 
e.g.

```
int dynamicOverlayIndex = mapView.getOverlays().size()
```

You can then remove just that one with :

```
mapView.getOverlays().remove(dynamicOverlayIndex);
```

Comment: I can't get that to work, because `mapView.getOverlays().size()` always return me 1, instead of the number of the overlays... And yes, I did it after putting the overlays on the map...

Comment: In that case you must be using just one overlay with many ITEMS, something like ArrayList<OverlayItem> mItems. You can also use the methods .add(), .remove(idx) and .size() on this list (e.g mItems.remove(3)). So you should be able to find your 'dynamic' item and remove it before adding a new one

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have updated the first post with the code, maybe that way you can help me better :)